# Using syntax-table information in elisp for tokenization

Tags: elisp, tokenize

I would like to use elisp to tokenize the following:

```
variable := "The symbol \" delimits strings"; (* Comments go here *)
```

as:

```
<variable> <:=> <The symbol \" delimits strings> <;>
```

based on the information from the buffer's `syntax-table`.

I have the `symbol-table` setup appropriately and am currently using the following function which operates correctly except for the string constant (either returns token or nil if point is not at an identifier or one of the operators in the regex).

```
(defun forward-token ()
  (forward-comment (point-max))
  (cond
   ((looking-at  (regexp-opt '("=" ":=" "," ";")))
    (goto-char (match-end 0))
    (match-string-no-properties 0))
   (t (buffer-substring-no-properties
       (point)
       (progn (skip-syntax-forward "w_")
              (point))))))
```

I am an elisp novice, so any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: BTW, if you're using this for SMIE, you should not need to do anything special for strings: with the above tokenizer function, SMIE should already correctly parse strings (and matched parens/braces/brackets).

Comment: @Stefan Yes, this function is used in my SMIE code but also in other places for tokenizing. I assume that it won't hurt anything to tokenize the string for SMIE,right?

Comment: SMIE should still work correctly if you tokenize the strings, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your `skip-syntax-forward` use is correct for strings.
I think you need to add a `cond` clause like this:

```
((looking-at "\"")
 (let* ((here (point)) (there (scan-sexps here 1)))
   (goto-char there)
   (buffer-substring-no-properties
    (1+ here) (1- there))))
```

to handle string literals.

Comment: Thank you. The function `scan-sexps` was the function that I did not know about.